# How to add pages into a page and slide the border?

Tags: javascript, html

Well, i guess the question is a bit confusing, but let me explain.

I need a page which can have multiple pages inside of it. Like this: [Multiple pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvM5h.png)

So, when the person click in the "+" button, it opens another page and divide the page into two or more. But the border between the two pages can be moved.

So, i have no idea what do i need to do that in html5. If someone please could give me an idea on how to begin i would be thankful.

Comment: https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/ maybe?